# Terraform Data block, all buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am trying to create an inventory list for all the buckets in a aws account, i amusing the terraform data source block in terraform to fetch the s3 buckets but can't figure out how to get all the buckets in my account, or which expression to use to get all the buckets, so i can do an inventory on all of them, please find my code below.

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "select_bucket" {
  bucket = "????"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "inventory" {
  bucket = "x-bucket"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_inventory" "inventory_list" {
  for_each = toset([data.aws_s3_bucket.select_bucket.id])
  bucket   = each.key
  name     = "lifecycle_analysis_bucket"

  included_object_versions = "All"

  schedule {
    frequency = "Daily"
  }

  destination {
    bucket {
      format     = "CSV"
      bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.inventory.arn
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> which expression to use to get all the buckets,

There is no such expression. You have to prepare the list of all you buckets beforhand, and then you can iterate over them in your code. The other option is to develop your own [custom data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) which would use AWS CLI or SDK to get the list of your buckets and return to TF for further processing.